# How give Id to @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions(){})){....}

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an asp.net mvc project and I wanna Disable all submit buttons while the form is submitting with below jquery code:

```
$(function()
{
  $('#theform').submit(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']", this)
      .val("Please Wait...")
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return true;
  });
});
```

An my form is as below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterCustomer", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions()
{
    OnSuccess = "success",
    UpdateTargetId = "listUsers"

}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.identificationNo, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.identificationNo)}})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.identificationNo, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.identificationType, new SelectList(itemsOfIdentificationType, "Key", "Value"), "نوع شناسه را انتخاب نمایید", new {style = "width:315px; height: 30px; padding 5px; margin: 5px 0 6px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; vertical-align:middle;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.identificationType, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

How can I give Id to :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions(){})){ /* ... */}
```

And another question is that is there any better way to disable submit button while the form is submitting and enable button again when the form submitted completely without any problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5th argument of the method signature you're calling for `Ajax.BeginForm()` is a the `htmlAttributes` object, which you can supply like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  "Index", 
  "Customer", 
  FormMethod.Post, 
  new AjaxOptions() { /* your options */ },
  new { @Id = "theform" } /* HTML attributes can be placed in this object */
))
{
  // form controls here...
}
```